# How to set default value for inherited field in Django with Multi-Table Inheritance?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models

I'm using Django 1.6 and have code similar to this:

```
class Message (models.Model):
   message_type = models.CharField(max_length=1)

class MessageA (Message):
    some_field_for_a = models.CharField(max_length=1)

class MessageB (Message):
    some_field_for_b = models.CharField(max_length=1)
```

I want to save new message to database just like this:

```
message_a = MessageA()
message_a.save()
```

But with current implementation I need to explicitly declare `message_type` like this:

```
message_a = MessageA()
message_a.message_type = "A"
message_a.save()
```

This is obviously counterintuitive, because `MessageA` should have `message_type = "A"` by default. Is there any *Django way* of avoiding this boilerplate code and setting `message_type` for each inherited class automatically (having in mind that [field hiding is not permitted](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted) and overriding `__init__` should be also avoided)?

Comment: Why would overriding `__init__` be avoided? How else would you access a super class? I feel like moving around that convention would only make things more confusing. That is exactly how I would do it. self.message_type = 'A' in the init of the child class.

Comment: You could use model signals, detect the class type as a subclass of Message, then set the message_type field if not set, but this is just hiding logic and more confusing imo.